# Remove "shop by price" in left sidebar with local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

I am creating a theme based on the rwd theme.  I want to remove the browse by price, but keep the browse by category.

I am using the following in my local.xml.

```
<catalog_category_layered> 
    <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
        <action method="unsetChild"><child>price_filter</child></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

It removes the "price" filter from the sidebar, but it removes all other content on the page. First photo is before the xml change, second is after the xml is changed.  Any suggestions???  [image: before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Catalog` > `Manage Attributes`

Search for `price`

Then edit the attribute, and change the following

`Use In Layered Navigation` : **No**

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!  Nothing like making things more complicated than they need to be!